# Get decimal value after dividing by a large number

Tags: c

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    double infre = 11e10;
    double c = 2.99795e8;
    double wavelength = c/infre;
    double delx = 0.600000000e-04;

    double nperdt = 2*((int)(wavelength/delx));
    double dt = 1.0/infre/(double)nperdt;
    printf("%.11f", dt);
    return 0;
}
```

Now `dt` is supposed to be very small. So is there any by which I can get that value upon division as currently I'm getting `0.0`

Comment: Use the exponential format  `%e` or the "general" format `%g` instead of `%f` when printing the result.

Comment: Also: recommend using `trunc()` rather than `(int)` as `(int)` is severely range limited for a `double()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can try for example to increase the digits showed after the ".". It seems your value rests somewhere in the range of 10^-13 and you are currently showing only the first 11 digits after the decimal point. For example `"%.19f"` will display a non-zero result. Additionally you can print them in exponential format using `%e`, which is actually the preferred solution in this situation.